# Load two 64-bit integers into lower & upper xmm, respectively

Tags: assembly, sse, cpu-registers

What's the easiest way to move two longs in say RDX, R8 into XMM0 where RDX is moved to the lower 64 bits and R8 to the upper 64 bits?

MOVQ will only set the lower and 0 the upper.

I am limited to SSSE3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Being limited to SSSE3 means no `pinsrq`, but you can do this:

```
movq xmm1, r8
pslldq xmm1, 8
movq xmm0, rdx
por xmm0, xmm1
```

There are many other ways, but I can't think of anything faster right now.

Maybe this, if it doesn't have bypass delays:

```
movq xmm1, r8
movq xmm0, rdx
shufpd xmm0, xmm1, 0
```

With SSE4.1 you could of course do

```
movq xmm0, rdx
pinsrq xmm0, r8, 1
```

Comment: Turns out I could use the 4.1 instructions (even though the compiler info reports the stated limit). Works perfectly, thank you.

Comment: Maybe an unpackhi could be faster than a shift. But I guess that depends on what port you're limited by.